# which library must i import for s = Sound()?

Tags: python, python-3.5

I have the following code snippet:

```
#import library
import os
s = Sound()
#read file
s.read('ffs.mp3')
#play sound
s.play
```

Which library must I import for `s = Sound()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably referring to [The Snack Sound Toolkit](http://www.speech.kth.se/snack/) which doesn't appear to be maintained anymore.